# Using Schwarz's lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $z_0$ be in an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Let  $ f, \phi: U \rightarrow \Delta(0,1)$. Suppose $\phi$ is bijection and $$\phi(z_0)=0,\ \phi'(z_0) \neq 0.$$ Assume, $f(z_0)=0$, prove that $$|f'(z_0)| \leq |\phi'(z_0)|,$$ with the equality if and only if $$f(z)= \lambda \phi(z)$$ with $|\lambda|=1$.

Here is where I am struggeling: We have here $\phi^{-1} $ is analytic. My ideas do not work with having this property, I am trying to use Schwarz's lemma but still have some problems. I am thankful for any help with that.

Comment: Have you looked at $f\circ\phi^{-1}$, which is an analytic function from the unit disc to itself?

Comment: Yes, I have $(f \circ \phi^-1)(0)=0$, but it does not help

Comment: Ok, that's a good start. So $g=f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is a function from the unit disc to itself such that $g(0)=0$. What does Schwarz's lemma tell you about such functions?

Comment: I think we still have to show $|g=f \circ\phi ^{-1}| \leq 1$, then confirm that $|g'(z_0| \leq |\phi '(z_0)|$.. WHICH is my problem to now that is how to show $|g=f \circ \phi ^{-1}| \leq 1$ for all z?

Comment: What is the codomain of $g$? What does that say about $|g(z)|$?

Comment: Yess I got it thank you,, Thank you alot